# How to import Auth on AngularFIre 7

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I'm trying to use AngularFire 7 on my project because apparently it's better to use with the emulators.
The way to inject Firebase is different and I'm having issues when trying to inject the `AngularFireAuth`. It looks like I'm importing from 'compat' when I shouldn't be doing that because now it's providers.

Documentation doesn't really exist on that. Has anybody figure that out?

Here is the code:

**app.module.ts**

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAnalytics(() => getAnalytics()),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
    provideMessaging(() => getMessaging())
  ],
```

then on my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class LoginService {
    constructor(private fireAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}

    loginUser(email: string, password: string) {
        this.fireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log(e);
            })
            .finally(() => console.log('finally'));
    }

}
```

And I get this error:

> src_app_login_login_module_ts.js:2 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(LoginModule)[LoginService -> LoginService -> AngularFireAuth -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!

Comment: Hey @MoblizeIT unfortunately I decided to work with the "old way" of doing that. Using compat. It's much more clear.